# Grails 3 with Fields plugin - show fields like numbers and dates in certain format

Tags: grails-3.0.9

A Book domain object has a publicationYear field.  In the show view it shows as 2,011 or 1,999 or whatever.  It should display as 2011.  It used to be a simple g:fomatNumber to get things right.

According to the Fields documentation at http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html one should create a directory grails-app/views/controllerName/actionName/propertyName/ and put a _wrapper.gsp template in it. They don't say what should be in that file.  I've tried various things and it looks as if it is just ignored.  The year is still 2,013 or whatever.

This will mainly be needed to display dates in various ways - mostly day or minute precision.  In this case I want to get rid of the comma.

Any idea how to do this?  I'm using Grails 3.0.9 and Scaffolding 3.1.3 because anything newer does not install templates and if one hand installs them, ignores them.

Comment: The easiest is just to use a string for the year. This works with the fields plugin, but necessitates specifying all fields to be shown, a lot of work just to get one field to display in a certain way:  <f:display bean="book" property="publicationYear">
    <li class="fieldcontain">
     <span id="publicationYear-label" class="property-label">Publication Year</span>
     <div class="property-value" aria-labelledby="publicationYear-label"><g:formatNumber format="0000" number="${book.publicationYear}" /></div>
    </li>
   </f:display>  There must be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly the publicationYear property is of type Date? 
In this case you can use the tag

```
g:formatDate
```

to display it. 
So if you only need the year:

```
g:formatDate format="yyyy" date="${publicationYear}"
```

See: [Grails 3.0.9 formatDate](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.9/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) 
Hope it helps